# What are these small holes in my foundation?

Tags: foundation

I recently removed the flooring in my house, without a basement, and found neat, evenly spaced (1/4"?) holes. What are they? Should I fill them?
[image]

Comment: Is your house on a slab, or a raised foundation with crawl space underneath?

Comment: slab, no crawlspace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These could be made by termite treatment. For on-slab houses, they drill holes in the concrete and inject poison (termites can burrow through concrete). Since the holes would be covered by the flooring they didn't bother filling them in.

You can fill them if you want but there's no harm in leaving them as well.